# Packet Generator in Tkinter

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, dpkt

Hi guys, 
 I hope you can help me. Sorry for my english, it's not my first language. I'm new to programming and I'm stuck in my first project. I try to program a simple data traffic generator with Tkinter and Python 2.7. 
I use the dpkt library as a basis for sending packets. In the beginn I wrote a script that I can run in the terminal and it works totally fine.

```
import dpkt
import socket,  random

# input
ip_dst = raw_input('IP-address of destination: ')
n = input('number of packets 2^n: ')
num =2**(n)
# packet size
b = input('size of packets (number between 1 and 5950): ')
while (b<1 or b>5950):
    print('Invalid number!')
    b = input('size of packets (number between 1 and 5950): ')
# script for sending packets
z=0
while z<=num:
    print z
    echo = dpkt.icmp.ICMP.Echo()
    echo.id = random.randint(0,0xffff)
    echo.seq = random.randint(0,0xffff)

    echo.data  = 'hello world'*b                    # changing size with factor b

    icmp = dpkt.icmp.ICMP()
    icmp.type = dpkt.icmp.ICMP_ECHO
    icmp.data = echo

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_ICMP)
    s.connect((ip_dst,1))                           # ip-address of destination
    sent = s.send(str(icmp))
    print 'sent %d bytes' %sent
    z=z+1
```

In my next step I tried to create a GUI to make it more handy and also useable for other users. So I created a mask in Tkinter, where I can enter the IP-address, select the size and the number of packets. Further I want the option that I can choose the type of the packet (ICMP/UDP). The code for sending UDP-packets I want to add later as a function.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFont
import dpkt
import socket, random

sent_packets = 0

# send icmp
def send_icmp(sent_packets, s1,ip_dst):
     while (sent_packets<=n):
         print sent_packets
         echo = dpkt.icmp.ICMP.Echo()
         echo.id = random.randint(0,0xffff)
         echo.seq = random.randint(0,0xffff)

         echo.data  = 'hello world'*(s1)

         icmp = dpkt.icmp.ICMP()
         icmp.type = dpkt.icmp.ICMP_ECHO
         icmp.data = echo

         s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_ICMP)
         s.connect((ip_dst,1))
         sent = s.send(str(icmp))
         print 'sent %d bytes' %sent
         sent_packets += 1
         mainWin.update()


mainWin= Tk()
mainWin.title('Traffic Generator')
mainWin.columnconfigure (0, weight=1)
mainWin.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

ip_dst = StringVar()

# Frame settings
mainFrame = Frame(mainWin, width=200, height=100)
mainFrame.grid_propagate(0)
mainFrame.grid()
mainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainFrame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)


# Headline
label_1 = Label(mainWin, text="Traffic Generator", font="Helvetica 11 bold")
label_1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,W), columnspan=2)

# Input

# IP-address:
label_2 = Label(mainWin, text="Please enter IP-address of destination: ", font=tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
label_2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,W))

entry_1 = Entry(mainWin, textvariable=ip_dst, width=13)
entry_1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,E))
entry_1.focus()

# type:
label_4 = Label(mainWin, text="Select packet type: ", font=tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
label_4.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,W))
type = IntVar()
Radiobutton(mainWin, text="ICMP", variable=type, value="send_icmp").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N,W), padx=15, pady=5, columnspan=2)
Radiobutton(mainWin, text="UDP", variable=type, value="send_udp").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N,W), padx=70, pady=5, columnspan=2)

# size:
label_3 = Label(mainWin, text="Select packet size: ", font=tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
label_3.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,W))

size1 = IntVar()
size_slide1 = Scale(mainWin, from_=1, to=5900, orient='horizontal', variable= size1, length=200, resolution=10, showvalue=0)
size_slide1.set(3000)
size_slide1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,E))

s1= str(size1)

Label(mainWin, textvariable= size1).grid(column=2, row=3, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,E)) 


# number:
label_4 = Label(mainWin, text="Select number of packets: ",font=tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
label_4.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,W))

num1 = int()
Label(mainWin, text="2^n packets: ", font=tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10)).grid(column=1, row=4, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(W,E))
num_slide1 = Scale(mainWin, from_=1, to=500, orient='horizontal', variable = num1, length=200, resolution=2, showvalue=0)
num_slide1.set(32)
num_slide1.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,E))
Label(mainWin, textvariable= num1).grid(column=2, row=5, padx=15, pady=5, sticky=(N,E))
number1 = 2**(num1)

# send:
Button(mainWin, text="Send packets", command=type, width=13).grid(column=2, row=6) # radiobuttons select value of variable 'type' which executes selected function (e.g. def send_icmp) of selected type


mainWin.mainloop()
```

The problem is, that when I hit send there is no reaction in the terminal. I don't understand why the script doesn't run. This is my first code and I'm working on this already quite a time. I probably make a little detour but I hope you can help me out and can tell me what the problem is. 
Thank you so much already.

Alex

Answer (score 2):

The script runs perfectly fine , its just the button you need to tweak.Probably you need to highlight the button when mouse is on it, use something like `activebackground` or `activeforeground`

I checked via `tcpdump` or you can use wireshark on the remote IP where you are sending the packet.

Comment: Sry for my late response. I didn't have the time to continue my project. Even when I tweak the button with activebackground, I don't get any reaction while pressing send. Is it possible that you cannot run such a script (for sending packets) in a function? Or do I have to work with classes?

Comment: ofcourse you can , just identify the main working blocks and create `def` for them..and as u already have used the function `send_icmp` its already modular , so u don't need to do much work on it

Comment: Thank you! I got it running. Now I use only the socket library for creating packets, its much faster. My only problem is that I cannot really change the type of the packets with the radiobuttons. Is it better to use different functions for each type, or just one function with changeable variables via radiobutton?

Comment: break it into more functions , this way you will be able to debug more properly too